# Ajax views (watch) table

Tags: views, ajax

I want to have a table view that remains on a particular page, but once someone anywhere on that site creates a node that is a part of that view, the view updates through AJAX and I see the new entry. Like a live twitter feed but for nodes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found it!: module [Views Auto-Refresh](https://www.drupal.org/project/views_autorefresh), which used to be part of the [Views Hacks](https://www.drupal.org/project/views_hacks) module (but is now considered a "Graduated module", as mentioned on the project page). `Here are some details about it, i.e. a quote from its project page:

> ... to refresh a view after a specified time interval. Includes advanced options to avoid reloading the whole view, and to avoid causing a full Drupal bootstrap at each refresh.
>
> Suitable for usage on liveblogs, activity streams, comment lists, and any other view where new items are frequently added.